# Why didn't the Bible mention David's height as it mentioned Goliath's height in 1 Sam. 17:4?

Tags: 1-samuel, david

> 1 Samuel 16:4 (KJV): And there went out a champion out of the camp of the Philistines, named Goliath, of Gath, whose height was six cubits and a span.

I just wanna know why the Bible didn't provide **David's height** to show the difference with Goliath's height. Is there any revelation or not?

Comment: The height if Goliath is in 1Samuel 17:4....not 16:4.

Answer (score 1):

The Bible does not mention David's height, but it does mention his youth.  We know from 1 Sam. 17:4 that David was the youngest son of Jesse, and left to tend the sheep while the three eldest sons were with Saul (vs. 13-15).  We know that Eliab, his eldest brother spoke to David as though to a child, chastising him for leaving his chore.

> *"...Why camest thou down hither? and with whom hast thou left those few sheep in the wilderness? **I know thy pride, and the naughtiness of thine heart;** for thou art come down that thou mightest see the battle."*  (1 Sam. 17:28, KJV)

The Bible tells us that Saul at first denied David since he was a "youth" (vs. 33), and that Goliath sneered at David for his youth and small stature (vs. 42-43).

So, we can conclude that David as the youngest of the brothers was smaller in stature than his brothers and most probably most of the Israelite on that battlefield.  The point of this record was, just as many times before and many times after, that God showed His power and His will through what appeared to men to be a much weaker and smaller man to defeat the enemy.

The revelation is that everyone who witnessed Goliath's defeat knew that it wasn't man's strength that accomplished the task, but God's will.  It was another testimony to the presence and existence of YHVH. It had to be a very heartening and uplifting moment for the Israelite to assure them that God was with them, and to show them to trust completely in Him.

It is a record for us that no matter how small or weak we may believe ourselves to be, when we stand up for God, when we stand firmly with Him, He will stand with us.

Answer (score -1):

Physically , people admire tall people. Even the unread prophets have illusion about short peoples and hence give false prophetic description to such. Thinking that ,due to their shortness, have been accursed by God.But as it has stated in the Bible,: God, looks through hearts and not canal appearance. David was choosed to killed Goliath , showing to believers that physical appearance unequalizes that of the spiritual.It also gives believers an assurance that : we can do all things regardless of our stature in Christ .

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  This looks more like a comment than an answer unless you can provide some references or Bible verse to support you answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Why was the Height of David not mentioned by Samuel?**

- God commanded Samuel not to acknowledge David's appearance or Height / **Gevoah (גְּבֹ֥הַּ)**, or the Height of David's brothers like Eliav (אֱלִיאָ֑ב) in 1 Samuel 16:7.

**1 Samuel 16:7**

> But YHVH said to Shamuel "Do Not-Look at his-appearance, or-at Height of his stature for I have rejected him | For [it is] not as The-Man sees | for The-Man looks at-appearances, but YHVH looks at [a] heart."
>
> (וַיֹּ֨אמֶר יְהֹוָ֜ה אֶל־שְׁמוּאֵ֗ל אַל־תַּבֵּ֧ט אֶל־מַרְאֵ֛הוּ וְאֶל־גְּבֹ֥הַּ קוֹמָת֖וֹ כִּ֣י מְאַסְתִּ֑יהוּ | כִּ֣י לֹ֗א אֲשֶׁ֚ר יִרְאֶה֙ הָאָדָ֔ם | כִּ֚י הָֽאָדָם֙ יִרְאֶ֣ה לַעֵינַ֔יִם וַיהֹוָ֖ה יִרְאֶ֥ה לַלֵּבָֽב)

This commandment not only applied to Eliav (אֱלִיאָ֑ב) but also applied to God's Anointed (מְשִׁיחֽוֹ) - David (דָּוִ֔ד).

Comment: Incorrect -   he looked at Eliab and thought, “Surely the LORD’S anointed is before Him v6 Surely the 'rejected him' was a clue :)

Comment: The commandment in 1 Samuel 16:7 not only applied to Eliav (אֱלִיאָ֑ב) but also applied to God's Anointed (מְשִׁיחֽוֹ) - David (דָּוִ֔ד).

Comment: Not in the context it doesn't - God *chose* David, not rejected him. The phrase 'God's Anointed' is a term Samuel used - not God. Samuel was presuming God's intention - as you now seem to be doing.

Comment: The context for everyone [is] the Heart matters more than Height.